# Access multidimensional Mat range OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mat, submatrix

I have a 3x3x1000 OpenCV Mat matrix created using

```
int sz[] = {3,3,1000};
Mat bigCube(3, sz, CV_8U);
```

I want to do matrix operations on the 1000 separate 3x3 sub-matrices. But I can not find a way to do this. 
The most obvious would be in a for-loop using Range, something like;

```
bigCube(Range(0,3),Range(0,3),Range(i,i+1));
//Do some operations...
```

But this won't compile. Is there a way to do this?